# Google Chrome doesn't print my Javascript-and-AJAX-generated content

Tags: google-chrome, printing

I am the developer of a webapplication.

Chrome displays my Javascript-and-AJAX-generated webpages correctly, but when I try and print them (via its native function) I get a blank page.

Printing works just fine on other browsers.

I have tried and print server-side-generated pages with Chrome and they get printed fine.

What can be wrong on the webpages of my web application? I think the issue is that those pages are dynamically generated by Javascript and AJAX.
I am saying that because I have just found out that I can't even save those pages correctly with Chrome (all the dynamic HTML is not shown).

I am on Google Chrome 13.0.782.112.
How can I debug and fix this issue?
Is there any workaround?
Is anybody managing to get dynamic-generated content printed with Google Chrome?

This problem is driving me crazy!

P.S.: some of my users are reporting the same problem on Safari :-(

**UPDATE**: upgraded to Chrome 14.0.835.202 but the issue is still there...

Comment: Can you please post some code for us to look at?

Comment: I just made a test [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Ypg/) and it's working fine for me. Are you using code that's different or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had exactly the same problem, though not in Chrome (although I didn't actually test with Chrome). On certain browsers (and I cannot remember which ones offhand - but it was either in IE or FF), any content that is added into the DOM by JavaScript is not printed. What is actually printed is the original document that was served to the browser.

I successfully solved this using the following JavaScript function:

```
function docw()
{
    var doct = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\"  
    \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">";
    document.write(doct + document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);
}
```

This is called when JavaScript page manipulation has finished. It actually reads the entire DOM and then re-writes the whole document back into itself using `document.write`. This is now enabling printing for my particular project on both IE and FireFox, although I'm pretty sure one of those did already work in the first place, and the other one didn't (can't remember which from memory, and it's not a project I can pull out to test at the moment). Whether this will solve the problem in Chrome I don't know, but it's worth a try.

**Edit** Terribly sorry, but I'm a complete pleb. I just re-read my old comments and this solution had nothing to do with printing; it was actually to fix a problem where only the original served document would be saved when **saving to file**. However, that said, I still wonder if it's worth a shot.

Comment: You are the best, Trevor!
Awesome! How happy I am!
Please everybody vote this answer: my question was quite vague and I didn't show any code, yet his snippet was totally spot on!

Comment: Ha, shows it's worth making a long shot occasionally! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

This helped me with a related problem - how to view/save dynamically generated HTML itself.  I came up with the following bookmarklet.

```
javascript:(function(){document.write('<pre>'+(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;'))+'</pre>')})()
```

I run this and 'select all' / copy, and then (in Linux) do 'xclip -out' to direct the large amount of clipboard data to a file.

Answer (score 2):

Trevor's answer totally worked for me- with jquery I simply did something like

```
$("html").html $("html").html()
```

worked perfectly